# Leaving water shut for 1 bathroom sink out of 2

Tags: bathroom, water, faucet

I have a small water dripping issue from one of the faucet in the bathroom. I have one of those two sink bathroom and one of the sink have a constant water dripping issue from the faucet where it'd frequently build up mold in the sink bowl. As I only use 1 of the sink out of two I just shut the water off for the other sink (by turning the values underneath the sink) however it got me thinking that would this cause any issue in the long run? such as water pipe bursting? if so I'd just clean up the bowl with Clorox once in a while instead of dealing with a water damage.

Thank you

Comment: The water pressure before the valve will be the same if on or off.  If the sink has a separate P-trap might want to pour some water down the drain every so often.  Or can fix the leak.

Comment: If you take picture of the valve, we can help you stopping the leak.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about the pressure bursting the pipes just because you used the shutoff valve to turn off the water to the sink.

What you need to think about is fixing the leak. It's usually an easy fix and there are many posts on this site on how to do it. You could also take pictures of the leak and sink and post another question and get a lot of answers

Answer (score 0):

Pipe bursting is not likely. If the pressure would be so high to burst pipe, it will start outside you home at the water meter.

However there is a possible problem not using one sink for long time.

The P-trap (under sink)where the drain pipe make a curve, will dry up. Normally they are always filled with water. If they dry up will might get sewage smell and mildew.

Filling up the p-trap every few days will resolve that.

Comment: I'm talking about the answer prior to the latest edit, which resolves my concern.